# ElasticSearch not filtering

Tags: elasticsearch, filter

I am trying to filter based on the categoryCode and I am not getting any result back,

I have tried using a filed that isn't analyzed and it worked, how can I make it work for this specific field?

```
  "categoryCode": {
  "type": "text",
  "analyzer": "autocomplete",
  "search_analyzer": "standard",
  "norms": false,
  "copy_to": "all_fields",
  "doc_values": false,
  "fields": {
    "raw": {
      "type": "keyword",
      "index": false,
      "normalizer": "lowercase_normalizer",
      "norms": false
    },
    "fulltext": {
      "type": "text",
      "analyzer": "standard",
      "doc_values": false
    }
  }
}
```

query for filtering:

```
   "bool":{
      "filter":[
         {
            "bool":{
               "must":[
                  {
                     "term":{
                        "categoryCode":{
                           "value":"PAYROLL"
                        }
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: `categoryName` or `categoryCode`, the mapping you provide is for the former

Comment: I updated the mapping for the right field  which is categoryCode

Comment: @JosephBouSaada, provided answer please have a look, and let me know if you need more clarification

Comment: @JosephBouSaada, any luck? feel free to ask if you have further questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are searching on `categoryCode` which is analyzed, hence goes through the analysis phase and creates tokens according to your `standard` analyzer(search analyzer) which lowercases the tokens as well.

**Instead of `categoryCode` , you need to search on `categoryCode.raw` which contains the keyword form of your document.** Also you might have to remove `lowercase_normalizer` as in your query, you are using `term` query which wouldn't go through your `lowercase normalizer` on raw field, and could cause `PAYROLL` to not match with `payroll`.

I've created sample index definition, indexed document and modified your search query to get the expected results.(Your entire mapping wasn't available, hence created a bare minimum example to explain)

### Index def (minimum)

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "categoryCode": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "raw": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "norms": false
                    },
                    "fulltext": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "analyzer": "standard",
                        "doc_values": false
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Index doc

```
{
   "categoryCode" : "PAYROLL"
}
```

### Search query

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                            {
                                "term": {
                                    "categoryCode.raw": { -->notice `.raw`
                                        "value": "PAYROLL"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

### Search result

```
 "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "so-60531341",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 0.0,
            "_source": {
               "categoryCode": "PAYROLL"
            }
         }
      ]
```

Comment: All I needed was to make the raw property indexed by ES.
Removing the lowercase_normalizer will not allow me match payoll to PAYROLL on that field.

Thank you @Opster Elasticsearch Ninja

Comment: @JosephBouSaada , glad it helped